# regex matches multiple lines

Tags: regex

Can I create a regex that matches the text ONLY if the whole text is less than 10 characters even if we have multiple lines?
example:

It should match the following:

```
123456789A
```

Or the following

```
123
45a
6b
```

But not the following as it's more than 10 character

```
1234567
8901234
ABCD
```

I used the following but it didn't work properly:

```
^.(\n|.){1,10}$
```

Comment: What language are you using, and how are you matching it against the text?

Comment: Your regexp will match 2 to 11 characters, because you have a `.` before the quantified group. Change `{1,10}` to `{0,9}`

Comment: @Barmar or delete the `.` and use `{0,10}`

Comment: Do you consider `\n` to be a character?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use as an alternative, since this will count the newlines as data characters. Your regexp will match 1 character followed by 1-10 newlines.

Instead, use a group that matches optional newlines *between* the normal characters.

```
^.(\n?.){0,9}$
```

Change `\n?` to `\n*` if you want to allow more than one newline between characters (i.e. multiple blank lines in the input).

Comment: I think any regex using `^`/`$` will need them to be interpreted as start/end of input and not start/end of line

Comment: That's the default meaning of `$`.